# Pixel count of image is three times expected value

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I am trying to get the Black and white pixel count from an Image. I am using image of 100X100 pixel with half white and half black.

This is the code I am using.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\yadav\OneDrive\Desktop\image_complexity\image.png")
white_pix_count = np.sum(img == 255)
print("Number of white pixel:",white_pix_count)
black_pix_count = np.sum(img == 0)
print("Number of black Pixel is :",black_pix_count)
total_pix_count = np.sum(img >= 0)
print("Number of total count:",total_pix_count)
```

Output I am getting is :

```
Number of white pixel: 14400
Number of black Pixel is : 15600
Number of total count: 30000
```

If I am using 100X100 size of image then Total no of Pixel should be 10000 why i am getting 30000
[image: This is the image I am using as input]

Comment: The image has 3 channels where each channel has 10000 pixels. Hence the image has 30000 pixels. You should perform the same on the binary image

Comment: How many channels does your input image have? It seems like you are using a 3-channel image, so every pixel has 3 values, hence you get 3 x 10000

Comment: OpenCV imread and videocapture always load an image as bgr24 if you dont use appropriate flags to load in original colorspace and bit depth.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an image of 100X100 pixel. So the pixel value will be 100*100= 10,000  for single channel. The image has 3 channels so 3 * 10,000 = 30,000 (So you got 30,000) but below code I'm converting colour image to black and image.
Hope it will work !

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"img path",0)
white_pix_count = np.sum(img == 255)
print("Number of white pixel:",white_pix_count)
black_pix_count = np.sum(img == 0)
print("Number of black Pixel is :",black_pix_count)
total_pix_count = np.sum(img >= 0)
print("Number of total count:",total_pix_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `30000` as the total pixel count is because your image is read in as BGR format, meaning there will be 3 channels for each color.

To see this, you can print out the shape of the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\yadav\OneDrive\Desktop\image_complexity\image.png")
print(img.shape)
```

Output:

```
(100, 100, 3)
```

Or print a small segment of the image that's 2 pixels by 2 pixels in size:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\yadav\OneDrive\Desktop\image_complexity\image.png")
print(img[:2, :2])
```

Output:

```
[[[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]

 [[255 255 255]
  [255 255 255]]]
```

To fix this, create a grayscale version of the image, and use it instead:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\yadav\OneDrive\Desktop\image_complexity\image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
white_pix_count = np.sum(gray == 255)
print("Number of white pixel:",white_pix_count)
black_pix_count = np.sum(gray == 0)
print("Number of black Pixel is :",black_pix_count)
total_pix_count = np.sum(gray >= 0)
print("Number of total count:",total_pix_count)
```

Output:

```
Number of white pixel: 4800
Number of black Pixel is : 5200
Number of total count: 10000
```

Or, if you will not be using the BGR image at all, simply read in the image as grayscale in the first place:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
path = r"C:\Users\yadav\OneDrive\Desktop\image_complexity\image.png"
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
white_pix_count = np.sum(img == 255)
print("Number of white pixel:",white_pix_count)
black_pix_count = np.sum(img == 0)
print("Number of black Pixel is :",black_pix_count)
total_pix_count = np.sum(img >= 0)
print("Number of total count:",total_pix_count)
```